# "Go to the next step" or "go on to the next step"?

Tags: grammar, present-participles

[Go to the next step](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22and%20go%20to%20the%20next%20step%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXk7-MmoLbAhVETbwKHQgTAEkQ_AUIDygA&biw=1855&bih=961) has more Google hits than [go on to the next step](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=961&tbm=bks&ei=au73WoSSD4ux8QWW_oWYAg&q=%22and%20go%20on%20to%20the%20next%20step%22&oq=%22and%20go%20on%20to%20the%20next%20step%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1943.2076.0.2208.3.3.0.0.0.0.123.184.1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.DKQ6FuXt8p0).

However, a native speaker (from Britain) told me that I should use go on. Maybe this is a case of American vs British English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Go to the next step" and "go on to the next step" have very similar meanings. The choice of which to use depends on context and the flow on the sentence. Sometimes a phrase feels like it should be abrupt and to-the-point. Other times, more expansive and wordy. Even the same author might vary this choice, to create a desired effect.